# VBA - get value from child node based on string rather than index

Tags: xml, vba

I am trying to extract specific value from an XMl file through Excel VBA.

I am working with the following sample XML:

```
<be05key_fig version="10.19.7.22" date="20.11.2022" company="Company Name" model="Model Name">
    <table head="Small House Test XML"></table>
    <table head="Transmission loss, W/m2">
        <row><id>Transmission loss frame, regular</id><value>12,0</value></row>
        <row><id>Transmission loss frame, low</id><value>11,0</value></row>
        <row><id>Transmission loss, calculated</id><value>9,9</value></row>
    </table>
    <table head="Renovation class 1, kWh/m2">
        <row><id>Energy frame, renovation class 1</id><value>70,1</value></row>
        <row><id>Total energy frame</id><value>70,1</value></row>
        <row><id>Total energy requirement</id><value>28,2</value></row>
    </table>
    <table head="Renovation class 2, kWh/m2">
        <row><id>Energy frame, renovation class 2</id><value>90,1</value></row>
        <row><id>Total energy frame</id><value>90,1</value></row>
        <row><id>Total energy requirement</id><value>10</value></row>
    </table>
    </be05key_fig>
```

Using the following script I have managed to extract the value I want (28,2), but I would like to avoid using index (2) but rather find the index of the row which "id" element contains the text "Total energy requirement"

```
Sub XML_import()
     
        Dim xmlObj As Object
        Set xmlObj = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        
        xmlObj.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        xmlObj.async = False
        xmlObj.validateOnParse = False
        xmlObj.Load ("C:\Key_Numbers.xml")

        'Print text for "value" element for a specific child node
        Debug.Print xmlObj.SelectNodes("//table[@head = 'Renovation class 1, kWh/m2']/row/value")(2).Text
End Sub
```

I expect the solution to be rather simple but have not managed to find it myself. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can target the table as you are, then by text = or contains the child id, then move to the following sibling value to retrieve the desired value. You also only want a single node so there is a method, as shown below, for that:

```
xmlObj.SelectSingleNode("//table[@head = 'Renovation class 1, kWh/m2']//id[contains(., 'Total energy requirement')]/following-sibling::value[1]").Text
```